# Wordpress -- Users cannot log into Wordpress site, call_user_func_array() except parameter Warning is shown on login screen

Tags: php, wordpress

On the login page of the website, this warning is shown

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_sensitive_page_meta' not found or invalid function name in /home/DOMAINNAME/domains/DOMAINNAME.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525
```

No users are able to login to the site. I am able to ssh to the site and view the file where the warning occurs. Here is the function in `plugins.php` where the error occurs

```
function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
        global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $merged_filters, $wp_current_filter;

        if ( ! isset($wp_actions[$tag]) )
                $wp_actions[$tag] = 1;
        else
                ++$wp_actions[$tag];

        // Do 'all' actions first
        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
                $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
                $all_args = func_get_args();
                _wp_call_all_hook($all_args);
        }

        if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
                if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
                        array_pop($wp_current_filter);
                return;
        }

        if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
                $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;

        $args = array();
        if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
                $args[] =& $arg[0];
        else
                $args[] = $arg;
        for ( $a = 2, $num = func_num_args(); $a < $num; $a++ )
                $args[] = func_get_arg($a);

        // Sort
        if ( !isset( $merged_filters[ $tag ] ) ) {
                ksort($wp_filter[$tag]);
                $merged_filters[ $tag ] = true;
        }

        reset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] );

        do {
                foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
                        if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
                                call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

        } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

        array_pop($wp_current_filter);
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate the specific code that is on line 525 as mentioned in the error log?

Comment: Please try disabling all of your plugins to see if you can login again. https://support.managed.com/kb/a2094/how-to-manually-disable-a-wordpress-plugin.aspx

Comment: @Propaganistas line 525 is 
```
call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));
```